# Container will not scale as a percentage

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a small project I have been working on but now realise I would like my container fill 100% height of the browser as appose to 800px. 
The problem I am facing is that percentages dont seem to work....!?
I have a JSFiddle here I have been working on [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tJugd/3652/)

```
<div class="slide2" style="height:800px;">
    <div class="staff2 staff-1" data-hammer="[object Object]"></div>

    <div class="staff2 staff-2" data-hammer="[object Object]"></div>

    <div class="staff2 staff-3" data-hammer="[object Object]"></div>
</div>



.slide2{
    height:800px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.staff2{
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    touch-action: none;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    width:33%;
    height:800px;
    background:red;
    float: left;
}
.staff-1{
    background:red;
}
.staff-2{
    background:blue;
}
.staff-3{
    background:yellow;
}

$('.staff2').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('clicked')){
        $('.staff2').animate({width:'33%'});
    } else {
        $('.staff2').not(this).animate({width:'0%'});
        $(this).animate({width:'100%'});
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you remove all instances of 800px, you can achieve this with 2 simple changes:

```
.slide2 {
height:100vh;
}

.slide2 > div {
height:100%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tJugd/3654/)

Comment: Right, so I had to be more specific in order to target the <div> i.e. ".slide2 > div

Comment: well, the second rule just makes all slide2 child divs fill the height of their parent, but yeah.